# How to play audio from a url in chunks (streaming) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I have a URL that fetches a music file from an AWS S3 bucket.

it takes about 10 - 15 seconds for the song to start playing, because it fetches the song first before playing.

I want to be able to fetch the song in chunks and play them in the html5 audio player.

So that once the user plays the song, it starts streaming while the other song is being fetched.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Waveform from './Waveform';

const appendBuffer = (buffer1, buffer2, context) => {
  const numberOfChannels = Math.min(
    buffer1.numberOfChannels,
    buffer2.numberOfChannels
  );
  const tmp = context.createBuffer(
    numberOfChannels,
    buffer1.length + buffer2.length,
    buffer1.sampleRate
  );
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfChannels; i++) {
    const channel = tmp.getChannelData(i);
    channel.set(buffer1.getChannelData(i), 0);
    channel.set(buffer2.getChannelData(i), buffer1.length);
  }
  return tmp;
};
const Player = ({ selectedTrack }) => {
  // const [blob, setBlob] = useState();

  const getData = async (selectedTrack) => {
    const fetchedData = await fetch(selectedTrack);
    const reader = await fetchedData.body.getReader();
    const context = new AudioContext();
    reader.read().then(async function processAudio({ done, value }) {
      if (done) {
        console.log('Stream finished. Content received:');
        return;
      }
      try {
        console.log('processAudio -> value', value.buffer);
        const buffer = await context.decodeAudioData(value.buffer);

        const source = context.createBufferSource();
        const newaudioBuffer =
          source && source.buffer
            ? appendBuffer(source.buffer, buffer, context)
            : buffer;
        source.buffer = newaudioBuffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(source.buffer.duration);
        console.log(
          'processAudio -> source.buffer.duration',
          source.buffer.duration
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('processAudio -> error', error);
      }
      return reader.read().then(processAudio);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(selectedTrack);
  }, [selectedTrack]);

  return (
    <div className="player">
      <Waveform url={selectedTrack} />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

what i have now gets the code in chunks but plays so fast and there is no way to make it play one after another

Comment: That sounds cool. What have you tried to build this. Could you show us relevant code and an attempt?

Comment: done that @EmielZuurbier